# Only render pages I've changed with Assemble

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, assemble

I've been using [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble) to create a pattern library. I have a pattern as different files that all get built into one file. I also have a number of pages that are the templates for the HTML.

The problem is that if I change one thing on any of the files I have to wait for the whole thing to be rendered, this is taking up to 30sec due to the amount of pages I have. As you can imagine, this can get frustrating and I'm only half way through the project.

Does anyone know of a way to make Grunt only render the pages I have changed rather than all of them?

Below is my Gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

// 1. All configuration goes here
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        dist: {
            src: [
                'vendor/jquery-ui/ui/core.js',
                'vendor/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js',
                'vendor/jquery-ui/ui/accordion.js',
                'vendor/jquery-ui/ui/datepicker.js',
                'javascript/slick/slick.js',
                'vendor/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
                'vendor/heapbox/src/jquery.heapbox-0.9.4.js',
                'vendor/jquery-waypoints/waypoints.js',
                'vendor/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/waypoints-sticky.js',
                'javascript/*.js'
            ],
            dest: 'public/javascript/scripts.js'
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        build: {
            src: 'public/javascript/scripts.js',
            dest: 'public/javascript/scripts.min.js'
        }
    },

    copy: {
        main: {
            src: [
                'vendor/jquery/dist/*.js',
                'vendor/prismjs/*',
                'vendor/bigSlide/**',
                'vendor/bigSlide/**',
                'vendor/magnific-popup/dist/*',
                'images/*'
            ],
            dest: 'public/'
        }
    },

    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'public/css/style.min.css': 'scss/style.scss'
            }
        },
        expanded: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded'
            },
            files: {
                'public/css/style.css': 'scss/style.scss'
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
        all: {
            files: ['*.hbs', 'patterns/*.hbs', 'layouts/*.hbs', 'templates/*.hbs'],
            tasks: ['assemble'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        },
        css: {
            files: ['scss/*.scss', 'scss/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        },
        copy: {
            files: ['images/*', 'vendor/*', 'CHANGELOG'],
            tasks: ['copy'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        },
        concat: {
            files: ['javascript/*.js'],
            tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        }
    },

    assemble: {
        options: {
            flatten: false,
            plugins: ['assemble-middleware-permalinks'],
            partials: ['patterns/*.hbs'],
            helpers: ['handlebars-helper-compose', 'handlebars-helper-include' ],
            layoutdir: 'layouts',
            layout: 'library.hbs',
            data: ['templates/data/*.{json,yml}'],
            collections: [{
                name: 'patterns',
                inflection: 'pattern'
            }]
        },
        pages: {
            src: ['*.hbs', 'patterns/*.hbs', 'templates/*.hbs'],
            dest: 'public/'
        },
        patterns: {
            options: {
                layout: 'default.hbs'
            },
            files: {
                'public/': ['patterns/*.hbs']
            }
        },
        files: {
            options: {
                layout: 'default.hbs'
            },
            files: {
                'public/': ['templates/*.hbs']
            }
        }
    }

});

// 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('assemble');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

// 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy', 'assemble', 'sass', 'watch']);

};
```

Can anyone help? Cheers.
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-newer

It works with two types of tasks:

1) Tasks that specify both src and dest files. In this case, the task prefixed by newer will be configured to run with src files that are newer than the corresponding dest file (based on the mtime of files).

2) Tasks that specify only src files. In this case, the task prefixed by newer will be configured to run with src files that are newer than the previous successful run of the same task.

Comment: Thanks Tom,

I've given this a go and it registers what has changed but still assembles all the pages. I may the settings wrong so I'll keep playing.

It seems like its something the Assemble team aren't to worried about - https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/451